# How to find the distance between bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

**Description :**

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the distance between the application, and nearby Bluetooth devices.

That, or only detect devices that are `x` meters away from the device with the application.

**Tried so far :**

I tried using the Bluetooth's signal strength, but it is not reliable, as it has so many variables other than the distance (rotation of the device, objects between the 2 devices, etc). For example, I kept an eye on a device that was still on a table, and the numbers went up by 10 mBw without neither of the devices moving.

I also thought of using GPS for distance calculation, but GPS's accuracy is vary big compared to the accuracy I'm looking for (+-1m).

I look for lowering the strength of the Bluetooth signal before searching (on newer Bluetooth versions), to find less devices within a lower range. But the people who have tried it say it is unreliable because even at the lowest energy for Bluetooth, the Bluetooth was able to find devices that are about 10m away.

**Examples around us :**

If anyone has an Apple Watch and a Mac, they'd know that it is possible to unlock your Mac by simpley being close to your Mac while wearing your Watch.

Also, car keys. When you get close enough to the car while carrying the key on you, the car is unlocked.

**Notes :**

Assume all the devices are Android devices with high their hardware. It's a special implementation, not for everyone

Comment: I think Bluetooth is not developed for this.

Answer (score 0):

A good discussion of techniques for calculating distance using Bluetooth devices is here: https://vimeo.com/171186055#t=40m15s.

With respect to the Apple Watch and Mac, Apple is using Time-of-Flight via peer-to-peer WiFi to determine proximity at that level of accuracy.

Typical automatic remote keyless entry systems utilize radio pulse, not bluetooth. More advanced systems, like Tesla's Phone key, uses Bluetooth on the phone device, but relies on the driver to physically touch the door handle to complete the process.

Comment: Does that mean it would be possible via WiFi? Both iPhone and any Android device have the same type of WiFi hardware, if I know rught

Comment: There is a wide variation in WiFi hardware and capabilities in Android alone. Not knowing anything about your environment (for example, what are these objects you're trying to range, do they have WiFi, and are you an authenticated user on all of them) makes it impossible to answer with any degree of certainty.

Comment: Here's discussion of RTT via WiFi on Android devices: https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/

Comment: Assume all the devices are Android Mobiles. And of high tier hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible but not much accurately.

You should approach to it like this:-
You should measure the signal strength, and then measure the distance using the speed of bluetooth (it usually travels 1cm in 100ps). Timing it would be difficult though.

Then, using the data you can easily measure the distance ( it is usually less that 10 m but can go farther).

You would get an answer but it would be really an approximate one. 
As per me, the exact measuring is not possible.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a reasonable way. I can't find the time of speed of the Bluetooth pulse by just guessing